# Sending kill -s USR1 from bash script stops the process while doing the same from terminal does not

Tags: bash, node.js, debugging, shell

There's a nodejs script called mimosa (https://github.com/dbashford/mimosa)

Nodejs uses USR1 to switch the running process to debug mode

Here's how I do it manually

```
$ cd myproj
$ mimosa watch -s # this runs node /path/to/mimosa watch -s
22:16:03 - Watching /Users/admin/Work/test-mimosa/assets
... # some more output
# check the pid from a different terminal
$ ps aux | grep mimosa
admin          79284   0.7  0.8  3153812 129272 s006  S+   10:16PM   0:03.57 node /opt/local/bin/mimosa watch -s
# send debug signal from the 2nd terminal
kill -s USR1 79284
# nodejs output in the 1st terminal
Hit SIGUSR1 - starting debugger agent.
debugger listening on port 5858
```

The same works if I run mimosa as a background process (`mimosa watch -s &`)

Now I need to automate the process: run mimosa, get its pid, send USR1, wait for user's SIGTERM, kill mimosa:

```
mimosa watch -s &
pid=$!

echo "mimosa pid: $pid"

trap "echo '\nSTOP'; kill $pid; exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM

echo 'send debug'
kill -s USR1 $pid

wait $pid
```

This script exits immediately, so does the mimosa process (I check it with grep again).
The output in the console

```
$ ./debug.sh
mimosa pid: 79516
send debug
./debug.sh: line 11: 79516 User defined signal 1: 30 mimosa watch -s
```

What's wrong, how to fix?

Comment: Here is your model: parent sends signal to child.  One scenario works, commandline.  I would suggest the problem is related to the environment of script - specifically what isatty() returns for stdin. In the case of a script stdin is not /dev/tty(a terminal) it is a file. And no, I don't know more than that.  You need a mimosa programmer to figure out what it wants/needs in order to be happy.  I believe you may want to consider  coprocesses. I do not know enough about your environment to say for sure.  zsh/ksh is required; bash does not support coprocesses.

Comment: mimosa is nothing more than a js script executed by nodejs, so running `mimosa watch -s` actually spawns `node /path/to/mimosa watch -s`. I think I miss something in bash, not very experienced with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could mimosa be sending a signal to its own process group when you send the debug signal? That would explain it.

In interactive shells, doing `./program` starts program with its own process group. If program does something like `kill -s USR1 0`, it'll never exit that group.

In non-interactive shells / scripts, doing `./program` will start it as a child but in the same process group. If the child does `kill -s USR1 0`, it'll kill the calling script.

You could do `trap 'echo ignoring' USR1 USR2` in your `debug.sh` in case those are the signals being sent by mimosa.

Alternatively, try turning on job control with `set -m` before starting mimosa.

See also [I have "trap 'echo ignore' USR1" in my called script, why does the calling script get killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908795/i-have-trap-echo-ignore-usr1-in-my-called-script-why-does-the-calling-scrip/21908796)

Comment: The question is quite old and I don't remember the details already. But your answer looks reasonable and interesting anyway :)